# python 3.5: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\python\\Sales prog\nacenka.xlsx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Have a nice error.

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
sales_shop = pd.read_excel('E:\python\Sales prog\sales.xlsx', index_col = "date")
holidays = pd.read_excel('E:\python\Sales prog\holidays common.xlsx', index_col = "date")
datecom = pd.read_excel('E:\python\Sales prog\date.xlsx', index_col = "date")
nacenka = pd.read_excel('E:\python\Sales prog\nacenka.xlsx', index_col = "date")
```

Error text:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\python\Sales
>   prog\nacenka.xlsx'

But if i write:

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
sales_shop = pd.read_excel('E:\python\Sales prog\sales.xlsx', index_col = "date")
holidays = pd.read_excel('E:\python\Sales prog\holidays common.xlsx', index_col = "date")
datecom = pd.read_excel('E:\python\Sales prog\date.xlsx', index_col = "date")
nacenka = pd.read_excel('E:/python/Sales prog/nacenka.xlsx', index_col = "date")
```

I don't have a trouble... But how? I just changed the slope, And in others he remained the same.

Comment: because `\n` is a control character that is inferred as a newline character

Comment: If you're working with windows, you should be careful with your path strings.

Comment: Prefix your filename text strings with `r`, e.g. `pd.read_excel(r'E:\py...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend you to sore the path in a variable once you have to use it multiple times, also you should follow the advices in the comments using \n can give you lots of troubles and in my case, using windows, i have to escape all the '\'.

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
salesPath = "E:\\python\\Sales prog\\"
sales_shop = pd.read_excel(salesPath+'sales.xlsx', index_col = "date")
holidays = pd.read_excel(salesPath+'holidays common.xlsx', index_col = "date")
datecom = pd.read_excel(salesPath+'date.xlsx', index_col = "date")
nacenka = pd.read_excel(salesPath+'nacenka.xlsx', index_col = "date")
```

Comment: it just happened to me, bu I have used both r'' or escape char. OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aY:\\filepath.xlsx'