# " read xlsx file " [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to read An excel sheet "temp.xslx"

my code is :

```
temp =pd.read_excel("D:\temp.xlsx")
```

the error I get :

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\temp.xlsx'
```

I googled the error but I got the same error over and over

Comment: `\t` is an escape sequence. Search for that term online.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730768/invalid-argument-in-pd-read-excel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683423/python-3-5-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-e-python-sales-prog-nacenk/46683717

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.read_excel("D:\\temp.xlsx")` or `pd.read_excel(r"D:\temp.xlsx")`

Comment: It didn't work :(  ty tho